# Java - Top inset not returning the proper value when painting

Tags: java, swing

having a problem with top insets not giving the proper value when painting ... i am looking for y to be just under the title bar but it is not working correctly and putting it 25 pixels from the top  where as the title bar only accounts for about 14 pixels .

Game Frame :

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class gameFrame extends JFrame {

static int width = 400;
static int height = 400;
static int topinset;
static int FPS = 30;

public gameFrame(){
    gamePanel gamePanel = new gamePanel();
    gamePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));
    Thread thread = new Thread(gamePanel);

    this.add(gamePanel);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setSize(width, height);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);

    topinset = this.getInsets().top;

    thread.start();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    gameFrame gameFrame = new gameFrame();

}
}
```

Game Panel :

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class gamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable {

public gamePanel(){
    this.setBounds(0,0,gameFrame.width,gameFrame.height);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.drawString("Width: "+ gameFrame.width + " Height: " + gameFrame.height, 0, gameFrame.topinset);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(true){
        repaint();
        try {Thread.sleep(1000*gameFrame.FPS);} 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by taking a look through [Working with Text APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/index.html)

Text rendering is typically done from the base line, meaning text will painted above the y position you specify

As has already being stated, a components `Graphics` context is translated before it's painted so that the 0x0 position will be the top/left corner of the component

In the following example, the first `String` will not appear on the screen, as it's base line is along the top edge of the component, whereas the second `String` has being adjusted so that it's ascent line is along the top top

[image: text]

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
    g2d.drawString("Hello", 0, 0);
    g2d.drawString("Hello", fm.stringWidth("Hello"), fm.getAscent());
    g2d.dispose();
}
```

Comment: +1 for understanding the true nature of the question. That you need font metrics to get the height to use for proper text placement.

Comment: thank you very much, i only noticed after i posted the question that boxs would draw at the right position but the text would not ... i will keep this in mind when drawing strings . Again, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

1. You are doing your custom painting on the panel so there is no need to worry about the offsets of the frame. Just use the getWidth() and getHeight() methods to get the current size of the panel.
2. If you want your panel to be (400, 400), then override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your panel class to return that dimension. Then use `frame.pack()` and the frame will size itself properly to include the panel size and the frame decorations.
3. There is no need for static variables. Those variables should just be instance variables or constants.
4. There is no need for the setBounds() since the layout manager will determine the size/location of the panel in the frame.
5. There is no need to make the panel visible since is it visible by default.
6. Follow Java naming conventions. Class names should start with an upper case character.
7. Why are you doing custom painting? Why not just add a JLabel to the NORTH of the frame and display your text in the label?

Comment: And after your done criticizing my code you could answer my question maybe ? lol

Comment: @user3087034,  I didn't understand why you were concerned with the offset of the frame so I gave my suggestions. All the suggestions I gave are valid. I already up voted and commented on the other answer explaining they did a better job of understanding the question than I did. That person also up voted my answer recognizing the useful information I provided. This information should help you understand how Swing work which should be helpful going forward. By the way notice how my answer got more up votes. Others appreciated my effort even if you didn't.